# MVC4 EF Database Creation and Seeding Issue

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, localdb

I getting an update error when trying to seed my database. Not sure if my structure is correctly setup but essentially you create a casefile which contains very basic information, then you create a more complex file by creating a ot or pt casefile which is linked to the casefile (I hope this is semi-understandable)

I order to make this a little easier to view the data I'm [linking the directory](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_Uf4KgCMRKOU2phQUxJUmRnb00&usp=sharing) to some of the code and the stacktrace error that I am getting. This only happens when I add the casefile code in the seed method of the Configuration.cs file. Somewhere its hanging on to an old definition for a foreign key relationship between the casefile and keywordId and settingId which were there in an early incarnation of the class but was removed.

I tried to delete the database and used Package manager to add-migration initial which gave me the file '201308191626305_initial.cs' which has these foriegn keys created. I tried to manually remove these from the file before running 'update-database -verbose' but this still produces errors complaining about Keyword-KeywordId in the stack track. All the tables build correctly and get populated except for the casefile table which gets created correctly but not populated.

updating with source files here. Very Large files...

```
    namespace MCPD_v3.Migrations
    {
        using System;
        using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

        public partial class initial : DbMigration
        {
            public override void Up()
            {
                CreateTable(
                    "dbo.Casefiles",
            c => new
                {
                    CasefileId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    UserId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    ClientId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    PTCasefileId = c.Int(),
                    OTCasefileId = c.Int(),
                    Submitted = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    Postable = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    Setting_SettingId = c.Int(),
                    Keyword_KeywordId = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.CasefileId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Clients", t => t.ClientId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Settings", t => t.Setting_SettingId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.UserProfile", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.OTCasefiles", t => t.OTCasefileId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.PTCasefiles", t => t.PTCasefileId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Keywords", t => t.Keyword_KeywordId)
            .Index(t => t.ClientId)
            .Index(t => t.Setting_SettingId)
            .Index(t => t.UserId)
            .Index(t => t.OTCasefileId)
            .Index(t => t.PTCasefileId)
            .Index(t => t.Keyword_KeywordId);
    ...

    CreateTable(
            "dbo.Keywords",
            c => new
                {
                    KeywordId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(),
                    Expanded = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.KeywordId);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.Clients", new[] { "SettingId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Clients", new[] { "GenderId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Casefiles", new[] { "Keyword_KeywordId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Casefiles", new[] { "PTCasefileId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Casefiles", new[] { "OTCasefileId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Casefiles", new[] { "UserId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Casefiles", new[] { "Setting_SettingId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Casefiles", new[] { "ClientId" });
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Clients", "SettingId", "dbo.Settings");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Clients", "GenderId", "dbo.Genders");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Casefiles", "Keyword_KeywordId", "dbo.Keywords");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Casefiles", "PTCasefileId", "dbo.PTCasefiles");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Casefiles", "OTCasefileId", "dbo.OTCasefiles");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Casefiles", "UserId", "dbo.UserProfile");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Casefiles", "Setting_SettingId", "dbo.Settings");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Casefiles", "ClientId", "dbo.Clients");
        DropTable("dbo.Keywords");
        DropTable("dbo.Files");
        DropTable("dbo.PTCasefiles");
        DropTable("dbo.OTCasefiles");
        DropTable("dbo.UserProfile");
        DropTable("dbo.Settings");
        DropTable("dbo.Genders");
        DropTable("dbo.Clients");
        DropTable("dbo.Casefiles");
    }
```

Here is the Class File

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace MCPD_v3.Models
    {
        public class Casefile
        {

            public int CasefileId { get; set; }
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            public int ClientId { get; set; }
            public int? PTCasefileId { get; set; }
            public int? OTCasefileId { get; set; }

            public bool Submitted { get; set; }
            public bool Postable { get; set; }


            public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

            public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }

            public virtual OTCasefile OTCasefile { get; set; }

            public virtual PTCasefile PTCasefile { get; set; }
        }
    }

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace MCPD_v3.Models
    {
        public class Keyword
        {
            public Keyword()
            {
                this.Casefiles = new HashSet<Casefile>();
            }

            public int KeywordId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Expanded { get; set; }

            public ICollection<Casefile> Casefiles { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, add table code here.

Comment: I can see why it is doing this now with the ICollection<Casefile> declaration in the Keyword class file. Would  I have to make this relationship manually in the Configurations file myself? My ultimate goal would be to have several keyworkds attached to a casefile. I would also like to be able to search the database by keyword and return all instances of casefiles that have that keyword in it. Any suggestions?